# How to remotely and temporarily start the desktop GUI in headless setup?

Tags: raspbian, vnc, terminal, putty

I have a Raspberry Pi running well in headless mode.  I am comfortable running things from the command line, and so have it set to boot to CLI.  I use PuTTY from Windows 10 to run any commands etc.

Occasionally, however, I would like to do something from the Desktop GUI (using the mouse for a lot of drag & drop kind of tasks), and I have VNC to operate this.  My problem is that I don't know how to turn off the Desktop GUI again once I'm done.  Currently I have two methods available to me - one that works (but isn't ideal) is I can get on the Pi itself and run

```
startx
```

This starts the GUI, then I can connect using VNC and do whatever I need to do, and have the option from the GUI to "Exit to command line", which closes the Desktop and puts the Pi back into CLI only.

[image]

However I have to get on the Pi itself to do this, I can't start that remotely (since PuTTY isn't graphical).

So from PuTTY I have been starting the desktop service

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

Which allows me to then connect to the Desktop using VNC as desired, but I no longer have the option "Exit to command line" from the Shutdown menu

[image]

I can open the PuTTY terminal and stop the service, but this does *not* put the Pi back into CLI - if I get on the Pi directly I'm met with a blank screen and blinking cursor and am unable to do anything from there (although a PuTTY terminal still works).

[image]

How can I remotely start the Desktop GUI for use with VNC, and be able to close that GUI again once I'm done?

Trying to do this with both RPi 4B and 3B+, so looking for answers that could work in both, but mostly need it for the 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to start a Desktop - which you can only do on the Pi itself.

If you want a desktop you can start/stop remotely you can create a [Virtual Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md)

> NOTE this Virtual Desktop will NOT share the screen with a real display.

There is no reason to exit GUI to get a command window.

If you just want to get to a CLI `Ctl+Alt+F2` will get you a session you can login to.
`Ctl+Alt+F7` would switch back to the GUI

PS you can use any of F1-F6. F1 is the boot login

Comment: A Virtual Desktop appears to be exactly what I'm after, thank you!  I can start the Desktop, do whatever I'm needing to do, and I'm even presented with the "Exit to command line" which terminates the Virtual Desktop when I'm done.