# Real VNC Viewer does not connect after reboot

Tags: vnc

I am running my Pi 4 headless using VNC. Everything works as expected, however when I reboot the Pi, VNC does not reconnect unless I physically connect a monitor directly to the HDMI port on the Pi. After that all is good and I can disconnect the monitor from the Pi.

Comment: How do you connect with VNC? Do you use the IP address or host name?

Comment: Connecting using the IP address Pradhyumna

Comment: Is it a static or dynamic one?

Comment: Static, IP remains the same for the Pi4?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run without a monitor you need to create a DISPLAY

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109282/8697

Alternatively  you can you can create a [Virtual Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md)
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106627/8697

Comment: Great thanks for the help, this was sorted... So with default settings and no monitor attached, VNC will NOT work, as the booted RPI4 will not have a video output system that can be used by VNC.
Adding hdmi_force_hotplug=1 to /boot/config.txt solves the problem. The Pi4 running headless, will now be able to be accessed via VNC.

Comment: Then please add your own answer and select the green tick mark.